# Lint TrustAllX509TrustManager issue with google-http-client

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, lint, x509trustmanager

I have these 2 libraries to my project:

```
    api("com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:2.2.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    api("com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev411-1.25.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
```

After I upgraded the AGP version to `7.4.2` and gradle to `7.5`, lint start complaining, you can find the error below:

> google-http-client-1.42.3.jar: Error: checkServerTrusted is empty,
> which could cause insecure network traffic due to trusting arbitrary
> TLS/SSL certificates presented by peers [TrustAllX509TrustManager]

Appreciate for any help here :)

Comment: Are those the latest versions of those Google dependencies?

Comment: TrustAllX509TrustManager means you break TLS security. So if you see this warning most likely something is really wrong in your app. **Do never use TrustAllX509TrustManager in productive/release apps**.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, they are latest versions.

Comment: @Robert after I removed calendar api libs and cannot see issue anymore, the problem comes from these libraries I mentioned above and I need these libs in my project